# CSS: Styling a dropdown menu list, but link style won't change from main navigation style

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS and I have no formal training, just kind of Frankenstein-ing stuff together. Right now I have a dropdown menu at the end of a main navigation menu. The problem is the links inside of the dropdown menu- I need them to be a darker color but they won't change from the light color from the main navigation menu. No matter what I try, the color is always the same! For some reason I can even change the color of the bullet points on the list (which I need to get rid of, too, but that's easier), but the text remains the same.

Appreciative of any help whatsoever. :-)

```css
/* (1/3) MAIN NAVIGATION BAR */

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #999900;
  font-family: caviar-dreams;
}


/* (2/3) NAVIGATION LINKS */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* (3/3) NAVIGATION LINKS */

#navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
}


/* (1/7) DROPDOWN MENU CONTAINER */

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* (2/7) DROPDOWN MENU BUTTON */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}


/* (3/7) DROPDOWN BUTTON HOVER COLOR */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8d7b8a;
}


/* (4/7) DROPDOWN CONTENT (HIDDEN UNTIL HOVERED) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px dashed #b89abe;
  width: auto;
}


/* (5/7) DROPDOWN LINKS */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* (6/7) DROPDOWN LINKS HOVER */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #8d7b8a;
}


/* (7/7) SHOW DROPDOWN MENU ON HOVER */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* AT LEAST THIS DID /SOMETHING/ ?
.dropdown-content ul li a
    {color:green;
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--| NAVIGATION BAR (1/2) |-->
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <!--| DROPDOWN MENU IN NAV BAR (2/2) |-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Drop Down Menu</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Art Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Custom Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events and Parties</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Studio Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `id`s are higher in the css hierarchy than classes. So `#navbar a` will always overwrite `.dropdown-content a`.

You can try this:`#navbar .dropdown-content a`.

Or you can rewrite as `#navbar > a`. This will only target anchor tags that are immediate children of the navbar. So it should ignore the anchor tags in your dropdown.

Or better yet, just don't use the `id`. There's not a whole lot of benefit to using an id over a class, and it tends to lead to these sorts of hiearchy issues.

Comment: you can also add !important after the color and before the semi-colon and the browser will then give order of importance to !important over the other color

Comment: One rule of thumb is to avoid using `!important` whenever you can. It should be used as an absolute last resort. It's a lazy way to fix the issue, and it'd be much more useful to just write it the correct way in the first place. No offense, Chris ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. All you needed was a more specific selector to override the `id`s.

```css
/* (1/3) MAIN NAVIGATION BAR */

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #999900;
  font-family: caviar-dreams;
}


/* (2/3) NAVIGATION LINKS */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* (3/3) NAVIGATION LINKS */

#navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
}


/* (1/7) DROPDOWN MENU CONTAINER */

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* (2/7) DROPDOWN MENU BUTTON */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}


/* (3/7) DROPDOWN BUTTON HOVER COLOR */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8d7b8a;
}


/* (4/7) DROPDOWN CONTENT (HIDDEN UNTIL HOVERED) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px dashed #b89abe;
  width: auto;
}


/* (5/7) DROPDOWN LINKS */

#navbar .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* (6/7) DROPDOWN LINKS HOVER */

#navbar .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #8d7b8a;
}


/* (7/7) SHOW DROPDOWN MENU ON HOVER */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* AT LEAST THIS DID /SOMETHING/ ?
.dropdown-content ul li a
    {color:green;
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--| NAVIGATION BAR (1/2) |-->
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <!--| DROPDOWN MENU IN NAV BAR (2/2) |-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Drop Down Menu</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Art Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Custom Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events and Parties</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Studio Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```